# How can I implement a scalable chat API in java, on top of tomcat + jersey?

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket, jersey, chat

I need to implement a chat server API in Java in a way that it can scale horizontally. I'm currently using tomcat + jersey + postgresql server side to implement a REST-like layer, and it would be good for the proposed solution to work with these technologies, but if I you believe the best solution lies with other java techs it can be discussed.

I've been looking at websockets, and some of the chat samples out there, starting with the tomcat websockets chat, but they are stateful and not well suited as they are to scale.

The way I see it, with a websockets approach I could take state out of each node, by storing it in the database, but then I'd need some sort of pub/sub mechanism for all nodes to push new messages to the clients they are bound to that participate in a chat room.

Since I don't want to reinvent the wheel, I was hoping to be able to put in place a solution by composing existing and tried technologies. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Cettia - Java server's [quick start guide](http://cettia.io/projects/cettia-java-server/1.0.0-Alpha1/#quick-start) and [clustering section](http://cettia.io/projects/cettia-java-server/1.0.0-Alpha1/reference/#clustering), which is designed to meet such usages.

A cettia application is designed to run on Grizzly, Netty, Play, Servlet, Vert.x, and so on and to share nothing between servers for easy scaling (pub-sub system is enough).

Here's some examples for you:

- [Servlet 3 and Java WebSocket API 1](https://github.com/cettia/cettia-examples/tree/master/archetype/cettia-java-server/platform/servlet3-jwa1) for Tomcat
- [JAX-RS 2 Atmosphere2](https://github.com/cettia/cettia-examples/tree/master/archetype/cettia-java-server/platform-on-platform/jaxrs2-atmosphere2) for Jersey
- [Hazelcast 3](https://github.com/cettia/cettia-examples/tree/master/archetype/cettia-java-server/clustering/hazelcast3) for scaling
- [jGroups 3](https://github.com/cettia/cettia-examples/tree/master/archetype/cettia-java-server/clustering/jgroups3) for scaling

I'm the author that project. If you mind it's in alpha stage, you may want to try [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere) out, which is similar to Cettia but provides GA.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to reinvent the wheel, I'd suggest a Jabber/XMPP server like ejabberd or Openfire (if you really want a Java solution). Its not RESTful but its an industry standard chat server and is horizontally scalable.

Answer (score 0):

please check out solutions at:

http://www.programmingforliving.com/2013/08/websocket-tomcat-8-ServerEndpointConfig-Configurator.html

or here:

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/tc7.0.x/trunk/webapps/examples/WEB-INF/classes/websocket/chat/ChatAnnotation.java?view=markup

Comment: thanks but none of these articles address the scalability issue at hand.